# how to used Jquery form with php while loop more than once

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm try to run a while loop, i also want jquery form to process it so the page doesn't refresh. So far the code work, but it only used the jquery function on the first loop and for the others loops it open new page. I need some help solving this problem. thanks in advance...
    (code)

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM linkUP_message WHERE to_mem='$from_mem'
            AND to_mem_burn='2' AND new_message='3' ORDER BY id DESC");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($num_rows < 1) {
    echo '<div id="new_message" class="addlinkuplinks a">&nbsp;You have no 
            message at this time.&nbsp;</div>';
    }else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $msg_id = $row['id'];
            $msg_to_mem = $row['to_mem'];
            $msg_from_mem = $row['from_mem'];
            $msg_from_memID = $row['from_memID'];
            $msg_subject = $row['subject'];
            $msg_content = $row['content'];
            $msg_date = $row['date'];
            $msg_from_mem_burn = $row['from_mem_burn'];
            $msg_to_mem_burn = $row['to_mem_burn'];


      $sqlName=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prociallinkup_members WHERE 
              email<>'$from_mem' AND email='$msg_from_mem' LIMIT 1")or die ("Sorry we
              have a mysql error!");
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqlName)){
          $msg_from_memAccount=$row["accountType"];
          $msg_from_memID=$row["hdw_id"];
          $msg_from_memEmail=$row["email"];
          $msg_from_memfirstName=$row["firstName"];
          $msg_from_memlastName=$row["lastName"];
          $msg_from_mem_pic=$row["profile_pic"];
          $gender=$row["gender"];}


      echo '

     <div id="linkUPmsg" class="linkUPmsg">
     <table width="100%">
       <tr>
       <tr><td width="60%"align="left" valign="top"><span style="font-size:
               12px; color: #CCCCCC;">Read Date:</span></td>
             <td width="40%"align="right" valign="top"><span style="font-size: 12px;
                color: #CCCCCC;">'.$msg_date.'</span></td>
       </tr>
     <table width="100%">
     <tr>
     <td width="5%" align="left">'.$profile_pic.'</td>
      <td width="87%"align="left" ><span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:
    bold; color: #999999;">'.$msg_from_memfirstName.' '.$msg_from_memlastName.'</span>
      <div id="requestlinkUP_text">Send you this message!</div>
      <div id="requestlinkUP_text"">Subject: <span style="font-size: 12px; 
     font-weight: bold; color: #0066CC;">'.$msg_subject.'</span></div>
      </td>

      <div id="readmember_msg"></div>
     <td width="3%" align="right"><div id="linkUPmsg_readR"><form id="readForm"
  action="read_message.php" class="readform" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data"
   name="acceptlinkUP">
     <input name="RfirstName" id="RfirstName" type="hidden"
   value="'.$msg_from_memfirstName.'" />
     <input name="RlastName" id="RlastName" type="hidden" 
   value="'.$msg_from_memlastName.'" />
     <input name="Remail" id="Remail" type="hidden" 
   value="'.$msg_from_memEmail.'" />
    <input name="Rdate" id="Rdate" type="hidden" value="'.$msg_date.'" />
     <input name="Rcontent" id="Rcontent" type="hidden" 
    value="'.$msg_content.'" />
     <input name="Rsubject" id="Rsubject" type="hidden"
   value="'.$msg_subject.'" />
     <input name="Rmsg_id" id="Rmsg_id" type="hidden" value="'.$msg_id.'" />
     <input name="Rto_mem" id="Rto_mem" type="hidden" value="'.$msg_from_mem.'"
              />
     <input name="read_linkUPmsg" class="msgAction" type="image" 
    src="/image/read_mail.png" width="25" height="25"/>
    </form></div></a>

     </td>


      <td width="5%" align="right"><div id="linkUPmsg_burnR"
      class="addlinkuplinks"><form id="burnForm_read" action="/burn_message.php" 
      class="burnForm_read" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data"
      name="burnlinkUP">
      <input name="msg_id" type="hidden" value="'.$msg_id.'" />
      <input name="to_mem" type="hidden" value="'.$msg_from_mem.'" />
     <input name="burn_linkUPmsg" class="msgAction" type="image"
       src="/image/burn_sign.png" width="20" height="25"/>
     </form></div><div id="burnmember_msg"></div></a>
    </td>

      </tr>
      </table>
      </span>
      </div>
      &nbsp;
              <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.validate.js"></script>  

      <script type="text/javascript">
      $("document").ready(function()
      {

      $("#burnForm_read").ajaxForm( {
      target: "#burnmember_msg",
      success: function() { 
      $("#linkUPmsg_readR").hide();
      $("#linkUPmsg_burnR").hide(); 


  } 
  });
  });
  </script> 

   ';
}
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use array for input type names , as;

```
<input name="Rdate[]" id="Rdate" type="hidden" value="'.$msg_date.'" />
//do this for all your input fields
//and the on php side do 
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: don't know how to do print_r($_POST); on php side (new to coding, I'm learning) could u please show me an example.

Comment: @Kasagi You would use `print_r($_POST);` on the `read_message.php` file. That's where the form is sending the data. `print_r` Is just going to show you what data was sent to the page. Used mainly for debugging.

Comment: how does that help me, i need help with the jquery script. the data are coming to the page fine.